# TypeScript: Type Mapping resolver object to result types

Tags: typescript

If I have an interface like this:

```
interface GetDomainInfoResolver {
  getDomainInfo: (domain: string) => Promise<DomainInfoType>
}
```

How can I create a Mapped type that results in an interface/type like this:

```
interface GetDomainInfoService {
  getDomainInfo: DomainInfoType
}
```

So that I can use it like this:

```
type GetDomainInfoService = Transform<GetDomainInfoResolver>
```

Is this possible at all?

The background is that I want to create a type interface between my GraphQL server resolvers (TypeGraphQL) and my client (@apollo/react-hooks).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to map over the properties and get the return type (using `ReturnType<T[P]>`) with a conditional type to extract the promise value type:

```
interface GetDomainInfoResolver {
  getDomainInfo: (domain: string) => Promise<DomainInfoType>
}

type GetAllResults<T extends Record<keyof T, (...a: any[]) => any>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]> extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never
}

type GetDomainInfoService = GetAllResults<GetDomainInfoResolver>
// Same as
// type GetDomainInfoService = {
//     getDomainInfo: DomainInfoType;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=5&pln=5&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gWwIYEsB2BJNAzOAVcaAXigG8AoKKqAEwC4oBnYAJ3QHNyBfc89YCC2xIAxtADiEYPGTosuAEoRGcADYA3QWUpR2Umakw44DABQ1EhhszZp2ASihEAfFAAKLRCkYQAPAbljAkhnbl5QSChJYABBVVUlRgBXVWBGXzwoCAAPATQaRiglETgWGl8AawgQOGwoPAAaKFMAOjakBiQ0EABtAF1HFygukGdXEgpqKB63KHQoKpq6vD6GJWAkljRgvzwZvtccvIL3TwRvP3RsLQBVVwB+KBuoBjQITRYw8giJfUtA3AAZUE6hQYicUSkcQSyhSaV80QCRkUyjUH1CAHoMVBAUgENAkIxyFioD9IdJ-si4MCWKDwRNidipnoKbIqQwkfJ8IQANyMqBcIA)

Comment: Thank you so much! After struggling around for two hours you saved my day.